# C# MVC4 Variable to Hold Two Columns That Can Be Updated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing a method for my MVC4 webapp (in C#) that will get a list of Blog objects and spit out a two-column list of the Category and it's Hits. The problem I am having with my provided code is that KeyValuePairs are immutable. The end goal is to use this variable (trimmed to the first 6 rows/pairs) to display the top categories (by how many times any article in that category has been viewed).
Should I be using a different variable type or do the update differently?

```
public List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> Top6BlogCategories()
    {
        // Get Blog posts
        IEnumerable<Blog> posts = db.Blogs.ToList();

        // Get Blog Categories
        IEnumerable<string> categories = Categories();

        // Create a variable to hold the Category and its Hits
        List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> categoryHits = new List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>();

        // Populate the List's first column (Category)
        foreach(var category in categories)
        {
            categoryHits.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(category, 0));
        }

        // Populate the List's second column (Hits)
        foreach(var row in categoryHits)
        {
            foreach(var post in posts)
            {
                if(post.Category == row.Key)
                {
                    row.Value++;
                }
            }
        }

        return categoryHits;
    }
```

Comment: You could use `Dictionary<string,int>` but you would need to iterate through it without using `foreach` because that would cause it to be read only.

Comment: @EvanL That is same problem that I had using KeyValuePair.

Comment: Not the same, just similar, the answer you accepted is a better way of doing it.  But... `KeyValuePair` is *immutable* you literally *can not* change the data in it.  `Dictionary` is *not immutable* but a `foreach` loop makes it `read only` which is different.  You can loop through a `Dictionary` without a `foreach` which would let you change values in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a ViewModel to describe the response you're expecting.

For example, if you're looking to send to your view a list of the top 6 categories and their total posts, I would use something like this:

ViewModel:

```
public class TopCategoryModel
{
    public string Category {get; set;}
    public int Count {get; set;}
}
```

Controller's Action:

```
public IEnumerable<TopCategoryModel> Top6BlogCategories()
{
    return db.Blogs
        .Select(b => b.Category)
        .Distinct()
        .Select(c => new TopCategoryModel
            {
                Category = c,
                Count = db.Blogs.Count(b => b.Category == c)
            })
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.Count)
        .Take(6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ and Count?

```
public IEnumerable<Blog> Top6BlogCategories()
{
    // Get Blog posts
    IEnumerable<Blog> posts = db.Blogs.ToList();

    // Get Blog Categories
    IEnumerable<string> categories = Categories();

    // Create a variable to hold the Category and its Hits
    List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> categoryHits = new List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>();

    // Populate the List's first column (Category)
    foreach(var category in categories)
    {
        categoryHits.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(category, posts.Count(post => post.Category == category)));
    }

    return posts;
}
```